# core-data NSDate searching for unique days and sorting

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data, nsdate

Lots of information on NSDates about the place, but I haven't found a clear solution to this.

I have a list of `Event` entities, each with potentially many `EventSessionTime`s.

`Event` <--->> `EventSessionTime`

In 1 table view I want to display a unique list of days that have `Events`, in another table view I want to show the events on a particular day (ordered by time).

To achieve this I currently have 2 NSDates - a day and time - and some overly complicated searching/sorting. I want to remove this redundant information.

With that in mind, how can I:

1) Finding all UNIQUE days with events, no concern about specific time

2) Finding all EVENTS on a particular day (duplicates fine here)

Any tips on how to better achieve this would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now have the following relationship. Still have redundant date information..

`Event` <--->> `EventSessionTime` <<--> `EventDay`

*1) Finding all UNIQUE days with events, no concern about specific time*

I can create specific dates where I know the time. The localised nature of my application means I can do this safely.

```
...
[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EventSessionTime" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
...
NSArray *res = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[self myResultArray:[res valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.eventDay.day"]];
```

You can infer my attribute and relationship names.

*2) Finding all EVENTS on a particular day (duplicates fine here)*

I use the following predicate to find all events on the specified day with. It does not return duplicates

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(SUBQUERY(eventTime, $x, $x.eventDay.day == %@).@count > 0)", <the day selected from the previous list>];
```