# Core Data and NSDate

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621179/core-data-nsdate-searching-for-unique-days-and-sorting) but I don't really understand the code... 
I have a core data database with an Entity and some attributes. One of them is named "myDate" and has for type NSDate.
Now I want to to display each date but eliminate dates with same day-month-year and display them ascendantly .

Have you got an idea?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621179/core-data-nsdate-searching-for-unique-days-and-sorting ?

Comment: @iPhone beginner that's the exact post he linked to in his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to have a UITableView with different sections for each date that has events sorted in acceding order then you can: (assuming your myDate attribute has the time as well)

- create a second date attribute (let's say dateForSection)
- Override the default setMyDate:

  - set `myDate` making sure to comply with KVC
  - strip the time from `myDate` (you will need to use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`)
  - use `[self setDateForSection:strippedDate];` to set the secondary date
- Tell your `NSFetchedResultsController` to use `dateForSection` as the `sectionNameKeyPath`
- You should then just need to sort the `UITableView` by myDate (there should be a method for this but I don't have any reference material in front of me right now, it might be in the `NSFetchedResultsController` as well).